# JavaScript - Chrome Extension on click jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to activate `jquery` in a simple form page with [chrome.stroage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) on `popup.html`.

Here is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "Test description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "storage"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "32": "icon.png",
    "64": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

and here is `popup.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" placeholder="place text here" id="inputString" />
    <button id="clickme">save it</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="saveNumber.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is `test.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Hello world');
});

$('#clickme').on("click", function(){
    console.log('Saving...');
    saveText();
});

var inputField = document.getElementById('inputString');

function saveText() {
    console.log('Saving...');
    var stringToSave =  inputField.value;

    chrome.storage.sync.set({'theText': stringToSave}, function() {
        console.log('Settings saved');
    });
}
```

and yet, when I click on the extension button...

[image]

The `jQuery` doesn't even say `Hello world` when the popup is clicked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Right click on the page and check on your console if there is an error stating $ is not defined. If yes, you must have forgotten to link the jquery.js and I also didnt see you linking your test.js

Comment: @GeneLim I added jQuery in the `popup.html` and it still gives me the $ undefied.

Comment: include the full relevant popup html code to show includes.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to learn to [debug popups](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging).

Right-click the extension's toolbar button, and select "Inspect popup". This will open Dev Tools attached to your popup and allow you to see the error.

---

If you did that, you would see that trying to load jQuery is causing an error.

Chrome is very strict with script security for extensions. By default, you are [not allowed to load scripts from any external sources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading).

You can [relax that](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script), allowing jQuery to load from a HTTPS-enabled CDN; but that's not required, and not the best idea - it's slower and unreliable.

You should simply download jQuery, place it in your extension and load it like you would `saveNumber.js`